# Node.js: Are schemaless URIs supported by request module?

Tags: node.js, request

Are someway *schemaless* URIs supported by [request](https://github.com/request/request) module?

I can't find any reference in the docs, nor googling.

Trying to request a schemaless URI (`//www.example.com/`), it grumbles *"Error: Invalid URI"*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called *protocol relative URLs*. They are not recommended [because SSL is encouraged everywhere](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

When running a node script there is no base scheme as opposed to when running in a browser. `request` has no way of knowing which scheme to use.

```
> url.parse("//www.example.com").protocol
null
```